# Why we need to update time zone information of jdk/jre?

Tags: java, timezone

I know that is required because of changes that occurs after the release of the jdk/jre, but why don't get those informations from the server?

As "from the server" i mean from OS. The question is: "Why doesn't Java use the time zone system from the operating system instead of having its own copy of the time zone database"?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "from the server"? Which server are you talking about? Do you mean "Why doesn't Java use the time zone system from the operating system instead of having its own copy of the time zone database"?

Comment: What do you mean? You are getting the information from a server.

Comment: The opposite would be to use the information from the local OS. But not all OSes have all the info Java needs.

Comment: It’s a decision that has been taken early on in the life of Java (probably by Sun before it was acquired by Oracle). There would have been other options each with their pros and cons.

Comment: As "from the server" i mean from OS. @JonSkeet That's right the question is: "Why doesn't Java use the time zone system from the operating system instead of having its own copy of the time zone database"?

Comment: Okay, now that it's clear, it would probably be speculation. I'd say the most obvious benefit is that the same time zone IDs can be used on Windows and Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my rough understanding. I believe it should at least give you the main reasons.

When Java was designed in the 1990s, a main design goal was that your Java program should be *write once run anywhere*, popularly abbreviated WORA. At that time cross-platform programs were not that commonplace. Porting your Windows program to a Mac or vice versa required quite some effort. Sun, the company that developed Java, was selling an operating system called Solaris, a Unix variant that not that many wanted to port to or from.

Different operating systems have different time zone data: different structure, different names for the time zones, different amounts of detail. Windows, for example, hasn’t got the full history of offsets for all time zones. What Mac and Unix had in the 1990s I don’t know. There were many Unix variants back then, and I am not even sure whether they all had built-in time zone information.

So relying on the operating system would mean that a program doing for example `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo")` (using the time zone class from back then, now long outdated) would not be portable because on another operating system the time zone would not be called that. The *write once run anywhere* idea would be seriously harmed.

I suppose that this was the main reason for choosing that Java needed to have its own built-in time zone database, the same on all operating systems. I also believe that the choice of the *Olson database*, also  known as *tzdata,* the *zoneinfo database* or *IANA time zone database*, was rather obvious. And from this choice came also the need for being able to update the timezone data, since the database is constantly evolving, especially since politicians around the globe are constantly (and eagerly, it would appear) deciding on new time zone rules.

Links for comparison:

- [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
- [Windows Default Time Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones)

Please notice that the former uses time zone IDs like America/Sao_Paulo, that is the *region/city* format, while the latter instead uses names like *E. South America Standard Time*.